# How to search for this string using regular expressions in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, replace

I am trying to find and replace this lines:

```
 <div id="fixed_bottom"></div>   
 </div>           
 <jsp:include flush="true" page="../includes/footer.jsp"/>
```

with this:

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="../includes/footer.jsp"/>
<div id="fixed_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And I do not know how to find them, because there are two line breaks in the sentence.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: if either Deepak's or my responses were helpful and/or correct it is customary to upvote and/or mark a correct answer (especially for future searchers who may have this question and want to see a correct answer). If our responses were not helpful please leave a comment clarifying what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

\n or \r\n indicate line break in a regular expression depending on what OS you are on. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more help on regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in Eclipse "Search File" with the regular expression box checked it will build the search string for you (if you had it highlighted before you opened search box). Note if you have to check the regular expression box you need to close the dialog and re open to get it to refresh. From there you can see Eclipse uses the somewhat odd `\R` for newlines.